# Где взять данные об общественных развлекательных местах со всего мира?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, big-data

Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда можно вытащить данные по развлекательным заведениям всего мира (кафе, клубы, кинотеатры, концертные залы) с названиями, местоположением, и, если возможно, фотографией?

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap, возможно, поможет. Охватывает большинство мест развлечений

Answer (score 1):

Можно из FourSquare вытаскивать, там структурированно по каегориям, ещё и с комментариями и отзывами